# Java mysql using url patterns

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm trying to build a java http server connected to a database (mysql) where one of my objectives are to NOT use a gui.

Instead, to let the "user" insert data by simply entering the desired input on top of a URL
For example:

in this url, the user is inserting his id number  = (123)  and his name = (JOE)

```
localhost/employee/add?id=123&name=JOE
```

or a remove example, removing a row by id only..

```
localhost/employee/remove?id=123
```

I was searching the web for a code example for over 4 hours and got to early morning hours with no luck :/

All I found was that it's called "url patterns" which you configure via java EE & net beans  or similar platforms (all that I've encountered so far..)

but none of the tutorials/explanations wont demonstrate how to implement that by sending queries and configuring multiple url patterns together.

Can someone explain, demonstrate this technique ?

Thousand thankyous in advance, Iguana.

Comment: Looks like you want a [RESTful Web Services](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html).

Comment: You can go with REST or SOAP..  Before getting proceed you need to consider those CRUD operations should be POST or PUT methods... And some RBAC concepts as well...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just read about RESTful web Services, I can't find anything related to "url patterns" :/

Comment: Make sure you are accessing server on right port number, The URL you has given did not mentioned any port number. like http://localhost:8080/employee/remove?id=123

Comment: Yea, it was just for the example